# Grammar find-and-replace

Tags: discussion

Grammar makes up a good part of readability in questions. Normally, I edit posts to improve grammar. However, there are *some* cases that are hard to deal with, like this one:

[image: “it’s own”]

In cases like these, a find and replace on everything seems like the only solution. Can we maybe do that?

Phrases that are never right and have exactly one version that works:

- it’s own (25,949 instances)
- your not (2,599 instances, none followed by a hyphen)
- into it’s (2,434 instances)
- you’re question (273 instances)

Usually wrong:

- your doing (1,312 instances)

(Feel free to add some.) These counts don’t even include comments…

I’m not even trying to be funny here. Something that went around and fixed all of these in the background without bumping would be fantastic. If it existed, we could do “its’” (1,458), “greatful” (670), “irregardless” (186), a whole host of typos (even the three “mostyl”!)…

Maybe this isn’t worth doing. Maybe the 22 “it’self” that I just fixed prove that nobody cares. There are another 493 “your’s” at the moment requiring a manual fix, and the split between it meaning “your” and “yours” looks to be around 50/50. The situation with the 568 “your’re” is similar. It’s possible that *everything* needs to be fixed manually, because somebody could be writing a question like this very one. Well, please discuss the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Comment: Doesn't editing posts push them up? Shouldn't this be bad on old posts?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: That’s why I’m asking – a find and replace could edit them without bumping.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for not getting you're question. :P

Comment: Please. Don’t. It’s not even funny anymore. I am literally dying

Comment: Sorry but, like you my Grammar Nazi has turned evil on it's own. Plus your not trying hard enough to suppress the OCD inside. Relax, take a break. You earned it. Maybe try something like I am doing to avoid all this? (Seriously, am trying to help)

Comment: "you're questioning my motives" "it's owning its own cleanup" "your note". Ok, I'm reaching here, and the fix is obvious.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: I was going four hole words, but I did specify hyphens on the one :)

Comment: Even in the little town of Code Review, there are simple grammatical errors everywhere.  I'm sure they make up a large fraction of my 1500+ edits there.

Comment: [And then there are stupid spelling errors...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plaese)

Comment: Your not is not as worthy as mine. It's own or nothing, no renting possible. You're question rather than answer, chalk rather than cheese. However, the chances of such phrasing in a question on programming are slim-enough compared to the amount of cleaning possible by a little magic, that I'm all for it myself. I change those in edits, and I'd prefer not to do it by hand if it is a machine-capable task.

Comment: How about "compliment", specifically when it is referring to two's *complement*.

Comment: "Your not in the if statement there is reversing the boolean before you check it." "The method is not ow, it's own." "The error is not your doing; this is a known bug."

Comment: *Into it's* is not a valid find/replace candidate, at least not without descending to a lower circle of regex hell. *With all the complications we've been getting into, it's tough to say what might happen*. Pedanticism aside, it would be nice to have *some* way to clean these errors up without bumps. They're UGLY.

Comment: @JonathanGarber: There’s a comma in between those. Without a comma, I’d say it’s almost the most valid one…

Comment: My point was that a simple find/replace has no way to know whether the error is a dropped comma or a superfluous apostrophe. Both situations would occur in the middle of a sentence without convenient boundary conditions that would easily be encapsulated in a regex. But hey, at least we can agree that pedanticism is awesome!

Answer (score 20):

If somebody writes "it's own" or "your not" in there post, theirs a good chance they're are other grammar and spelling errors that need fixed as well.  These would be missed by an automated process.  I'd rather see the questions edited manually so that everything that needs attention gets fixed in each one.

Comment: Yes, they would. On the other hand, their our 26 thousand of them.

Comment: *needed fix as well. This would be missed by a automated process.

Comment: @minitech Maybe a moderation queque for such autodetected posts? Automatic corrections tend to be error-prone and hard to debug. Advanced AI would be needed to do such corrections safely, human exception handlers are the only option till then.

Comment: It's making me twitchy not to fix your "errors" here, in spite of my knowledge that they're intentional.

Comment: Yes, but then further edits require less work, generate fewer typos. Of 26,000 how many will be edited manually anyway? 100? 1000? Kill 26,000 horrors knowing that more than 25,999 are going to be correct, even if it leaves another 20,000 in those posts which no-one is ever going to get to.

Comment: @PompousQWoodger If they're not going to be edited anyway, we might as well do nothing to them. On the other hand, if we're going to put any effort at all into these questions, we might as well fix as much as we can in the 100 or 1000 of them that we are going to edit.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot, now I'm going to have to go and make 26k edits. Come on SE, just run a replacement on the database! Save my Christmas!

Comment: Man, gimme half of those edit's.